# Archunit: How to control usage one class in all other packages

Tags: java, archunit

I have class from the different repository which has public methods and has been used in the class with import.

Example:

**com.tables.Field** class which has public Methods from different repository and has been used in the project.

I want above Field class to be used only by class in the following package  **com.test.FieldImpl**
and should not be used by other packages in the project.

How to write Predicate for this condition

```
private final ArchRule table_should_access_only_impl = classes().that().
            haveFullyQualifiedName("com.tables.Field").should().accessTargetWhere(?);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for something like this:

```java
ArchRule table_should_access_only_impl = noClasses()
    .that().doNotHaveFullyQualifiedName("com.test.FieldImpl")
    .should().accessClassesThat().haveFullyQualifiedName("com.tables.Field");
```

Instead of [`accessClassesThat`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#accessClassesThat()), you can also use [`dependOnClassesThat`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#dependOnClassesThat()), which covers more dependencies than just field access or method calls.